# Python MultiProcessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pika

I'm using Python Python Multiprocessing for a RabbitMQ Consumers.
On Application Start I create 4 WorkerProcesses.

```
def start_workers(num=4):
    for i in xrange(num):
        process = WorkerProcess()
        process.start()
```

Below you find my WorkerClass.
The Logic works so far, I create 4 parallel Consumer Processes.
But the Problem is after a Process got killed. I want to create a new Process. The Problem  in the Logic below is that the new Process is created as child process from the old one and after a while the memory runs out of space.
Is there any possibility with Python Multiprocessing to start a new process and kill the old one correctly?

```
class WorkerProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

def ___init__(self):
    app.logger.info('%s: Starting new Thread!', self.name)
    super(multiprocessing.Process, self).__init__()

def shutdown(self):
    process = WorkerProcess()
    process.start()
    return True

def kill(self):
    start_workers(1)
    self.terminate()

def run(self):
    try:
        # Connect to RabbitMQ
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(app.config.get('RABBIT_USER'), app.config.get('RABBIT_PASS'))
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host=app.config.get('RABBITMQ_SERVER'), port=5672, credentials=credentials))
        channel = connection.channel()

        # Declare the Queue
        channel.queue_declare(queue='screenshotlayer',
                              auto_delete=False,
                              durable=True)

        app.logger.info('%s: Start to consume from RabbitMQ.', self.name)
        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='screenshotlayer')
        channel.start_consuming()
        app.logger.info('%s: Thread is going to sleep!', self.name)

        # do what channel.start_consuming() does but with stoppping signal
        #while self.stop_working.is_set():
        #    channel.transport.connection.process_data_events()

        channel.stop_consuming()
        connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
               self.shutdown()
    return 0
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main process, keep track of your subprocesses (in a `list`) and loop over them with `.join(timeout=50)` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join).

Then check is he is alive (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive).

If he is not, replace him with a fresh one.

```
def start_workers(n):
    wks = []
    for _ in range(n):
        wks.append(WorkerProcess())
        wks[-1].start()
    while True:
        #Remove all terminated process
        wks = [p for p in wks if p.is_alive()]

        #Start new process
        for i in range(n-len(wks)):
            wks.append(WorkerProcess())
            wks[-1].start()
```

Comment: But I don't wont Subprocces. I start Thread:1, Tread:2, Thread:3, Thread:4. Now If Thread:1 got killed,it generates a new subprocess Thread:1:1, and the next Thread would be Thread:1:1:1 this goes so long until there is no memory anymore. I want that if thread:1 got killed a new Thread will be generated Thread:XY.

Comment: I you can keep your main process busy, he can monitor the 4 threads and if one terminates, he can relaunch one. If your function `start_worker` have to return after starting, start a thread which will do the rest (launch 4 threads and watching them)

Comment: Understood, thanks.
But if I generate a new Thread I get a Assertation Error, cannot start Process twice
`AssertionError: cannot start a process twice`

Comment: Strange, it should only start the last thread. Are you sure you didn't forgot the «-» in `wks[-1].start()`?

Comment: You are doing a `.start()` on a thread that was already started.

Answer (score 1):

I would not handle the process pool management myself. Instead, I would use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.future` module.

No need to inherit the `WorkerProcess` to inherit the `Process` class. Just write your actual code in the class and then submit it to a process pool executor. The executor would have a pool of processes always ready to execute your tasks.

This way you can keep things simple and less headache for you.

You can read more about in my blog post here: http://masnun.com/2016/03/29/python-a-quick-introduction-to-the-concurrent-futures-module.html

Example Code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def return_after_5_secs(message):
    sleep(5)
    return message

pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(3)

future = pool.submit(return_after_5_secs, ("hello"))
print(future.done())
sleep(5)
print(future.done())
print("Result: " + future.result())
```

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if there is a exception in return_after_5_secs function and the Process got killed, will it generate a new process. 
In my case I need always 4 consumers running:
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will always have the number of processes you mention. In my code example (`pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(3)`) I have 3 processes in the pool.